# How to create replicas in docker-compose when `scale` is deprecated?

Tags: docker-compose

According to docker-compose issue #5586, [`scale` is deprecated](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5586). The replacement is [`deploy.replicas`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy) but that latter is not handled by `docker-compose`, only by `docker stack` implying you have to run Docker in swarm mode.

As alternate solutions, you can scale services from the command line with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up --scale app=3
```

I'm not too fond of this solution since in my understanding `docker-compose.yml` is supposed to be self-contained and should not depend on command line options.

Another option is to run docker-compose in [`--compatibility` mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-mode):

```
docker-compose --compatibility up
```

In that case, `docker-compose` will translate some `deploy` entries into their *version 2* equivalent. But because of the name of that option, and because of the warnings in the docs, it does not look like a mid- to long-term solution.

What would you suggest to replace the docker-compose *v2* `scale` option?

Answer (score 3):

[@decoomanj on github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5586#issuecomment-375580132) indicated that `scale` has to be replaced by `deploy` in conjunction with `replicas`.

According to [mrampant-nist on github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5586#issuecomment-475250276) one has to use `--compatibility` as well.

Let's test this. First of all all docker-compose.yml is needed:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      scale: 6
```

and issuing:

```
docker-compose up
```

results in:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.nginx: 'scale'
```

Applying @decoomanj's suggestion, i.e. replacing replicas:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      deploy:
        replicas: 6
```

results in:

```
WARNING: Some services (nginx) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
```

Running `docker-compose --compatibility up` starts 6 services:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f19aa54634d7        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp              6233_nginx_5
749cff4ac1c3        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        80/tcp              6233_nginx_3
b86ed7b217fe        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 seconds ago       Up 1 second         80/tcp              6233_nginx_6
0b92e5ef4a0e        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        80/tcp              6233_nginx_2
e414bca52b53        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp              6233_nginx_4
e9f33dc634a8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        80/tcp              6233_nginx_1
```

In conclusion, `replicas` has to be replaced by `deploy` and `replicas` and `--compatibility` is needed to solve the issue.